# Cannot find module 'map-cache'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sharepoint, web-parts, spfx

When I gulp serve my SPFx Webpart getting this error, also when creating a new webpart the result is same as below. I had searched a lot but I have not found any solution. Guys please help me to find out what is wrong.

```
D:\Mileage>gulp serve
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'map-cache'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cdku7557807\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\gulp\node_modules\parse-filepath\index.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

install npm package

```
npm install map-cache --save
```

Comment: still have issue